# Why am I getting a MissingMethodException when using a Script# assembly from another .NET assembly?

Tags: script#

I'm testing Script# right now and created a simple Script# class library with a single class.

The class has a method that does something like this:

```
public static string[] SplitName(string name)
{
    return name.Split(' ');
}
```

It compiles fine and generates the JS output file but when I reference this assembly from my NUnit project and try to test it a MissingMethodException is thrown.

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found 'System.String[] System.String.Split(Char)'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose solution from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260153/using-script-code-with-string-operations-in-standart-c-sharp-net-project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that even when it is a valid .net assembly, it references a custom mscorlib.dll. See my answer to your other question to see the way I do it. [Is it possible to write code in C# and use Script# to share it between .NET assemblies and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460012/is-it-possible-to-write-code-in-c-sharp-and-use-script-to-share-it-between-net)

Comment: Adding link to the github issue on the same topic for reference https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/199