# Is it possible to write code in C# and use Script# to share it between .NET assemblies and JavaScript?

Tags: script#

I'm investigating using Script# to share some of our C# business logic with the client-side by compiling it to JavaScript.

Question is, is it possible to reference a Script# class library from another .NET assembly? I've tried doing it in a quick test and [failed miserably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459579/why-am-i-getting-a-missingmethodexception-when-using-a-script-assembly-from-ano).

Looking through the Script# source code leads me to believe this won't be possible because no implementation code has been provided for Script#'s mscorlib classes. [See the String class](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/master/src/Libraries/CoreLib/String.cs) as an example.

If someone can provide a definitive answer on this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I encountered with such problem too, and there is [more detail description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260153/using-script-code-with-string-operations-in-standart-c-sharp-net-project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is to create two projects. The #script proyect and the .net class library proyect. Then I link each of the .cs files (Adding existing items as linked).

You can use #IF SCRIPTSHARP .... #ENDIF preprocesors to avoid compiling specific #script attributes.

Finally you can compile both libraries and reuse the code.

I use it every day and it work perfectly well.

Comment: +1 on that ... you do need to be careful about what you reference. As long as you don't reference script-specific stuff or .net specific stuff you're fine ... in practice, some ifdefs go a long way. It would be interesting to improve this experience where possible. If there are suggestions, please open them as issues on the github repo for Script# for consideration.

Comment: Thanks NikhilK, Another thing I do is to create some kind of mock attributes (ScriptNameAttribute for example) with the same parameters, so that I use exactly the same .cs file without worring about the ugly #IF #ENDIF.